# Infinite carousel - with setInterval

Tags: javascript, css, carousel

Please you can check this code :

I have a problem when I want to remove `move` class

```js
let lis = document.querySelectorAll('li')
let arr =  [];

for (let i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
 arr.push(lis[i]);
}

setInterval( function () {
  let splice = arr.splice(0,1);
    splice[0].classList.add('move');
    arr.push(splice[0]);
},3500)
```

```css
.red {
  background-color: red;
}
.green {
  background-color: green;
}
.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.slideshow {
   width: 350px;
   height: 200px;
   overflow: hidden;
   border: 3px solid #F2F2F2;
}

.slideshow ul {
    /* 4 images donc 4 x 100% */
   width: 400%;
   height: 200px;
   padding:0; margin:0;
   list-style: none;
   transition: 2s;
}
.slideshow li {
   float: left;
   width: 25%;
   height: 200px;
   transition: .5s;
}
.move {
  margin-left: -25%;
  transition: .5s;
}
```

```html
<div class="slideshow">
 <ul>
  <li class='red'></li>
  <li class='green'></li>
  <li class='yellow'></li>
  <li class='blue'></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Thanks a lot

**EDIT**

`https://jsfiddle.net/o00nu4w8/`

With console.log, I have the good effect as I want, but any animation appears

Comment: please specify what exactly you want to achieve

Comment: Sorry, when I push the splice variable in my array (arr is name) I want to remove the move class CSS for infinite effect carousel. I hope to understand :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try something like this. Use an index that you increment in each step and when you reach the last on you remove all the `move` classes and you start again.

```js
let lis = document.querySelectorAll('li')
let c = 0;


setInterval(function() {
  if (c == lis.length -1) {
    c = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < lis.length; i++)
      lis[i].classList.remove('move');
  } else {
    lis[c].classList.add('move');
    c++;
  }
}, 3500)
```

```css
.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.slideshow {
  width: 350px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 3px solid #F2F2F2;
}

.slideshow ul {
  /* 4 images donc 4 x 100% */
  width: 400%;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  transition: 2s;
}

.slideshow li {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  height: 200px;
  transition: .5s;
}

.move {
  margin-left: -25%;
  transition: .5s;
}
```

```html
<div class="slideshow">
  <ul>
    <li class='red'></li>
    <li class='green'></li>
    <li class='yellow'></li>
    <li class='blue'></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: And If I want to remove `move` class after executed setInterval ?

Comment: @Jonathan you mean in each step ?

Comment: Yes :) And I search for them, but I can't find a good solution.

Comment: @Jonathan since you have an index you can for example add move to current element an remove it from index-1 element. Simply becarefull about edges when the index is 0 and when the index is the end

Comment: Yes, I tried this before, but the animation doesn't worked because, the logical part is inside of setInterval, and we add the `move` class and we remove index -1.

Comment: Check that code : `https://jsfiddle.net/o00nu4w8/`
With console.log, I have the good effect as I want, but no animation appears

Comment: @Jonathan this is due to the nature of the animation, if i change the way it animates it's ok ?

Comment: You can edited my fiddle as you want, because I don't understand ^^ I tried most things and I can't solved this problem

Comment: @Jonathan here is another way to do it https://jsfiddle.net/0e98d2mz/2/ by removing/adding the class ;) the idea is to have the element absolute position so you can remove the class with breaking the animation

Comment: Ok, for me it's a best solution ! Thanks a lot